# NMinimize- objective function should be scalar-valued

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I get the following error when trying to use the NMinimize function. See image for full code.

```
NMinimize::objfs: The objective function {{a (0.000081 a-0.0000169425 b-2.78856*10^-6 c)+b (-0.00001692 a+0.000025 b+0.0000113 c)+(-2.78856*10^-6 a+0.0000113 b+0.000064 c) c}} should be scalar-valued.
```

[image]
Okay so I figured out what the problem is but not how to fix it.  The matrix multiplication happens correctly, but instead of returning a scalar, Mathematica returns a list with one item which causes an error with ArgMin.  Is there any way around this without adding another function to return the first (only) item of the list?  I'd rather have the matrix-vector operations return a scalar value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQmy6.png)

Comment: `Transpose[{a,b,c}]` should give you an error message. `Y={a,b,c};
r={{1.*.009*.009,-0.376*.009*.005,-0.03873*.009*.008},
   {-0.3765*.009*.005,1*.005*.005,0.2825*.005*.008},
   {-0.3873*.009*.008,0.2825*.005*.008,1*.008*.008}};
NMinimize[{Y.r.Y,a+b+c==1&&0<a<1&&0<b<1&&0<c<1}, {a,b,c}]` minimizes just fine for me. Please scrape-n-paste to check exactly this input in a fresh notebook.

Answer (score 0):

To use your linear algebra formula define `Y` as a single row 2d matrix:

```
Y={{a,b,c}}
```

then you can do `Y.r.Transpose[Y]` . The result is a single element depth 2 array, so to get your scalar result:

```
(Y.r.Transpose[Y])[[1,1]]
```

> a (0.000081 a - 0.0000169425 b - 0.0000278856 c) + 
>    b (-0.00001692 a + 0.000025 b + 0.0000113 c) + (-2.78856*10^-6 a + 
>       0.0000113 b + 0.000064 c) c

(This is same result as approach in comment.)